# cgitb continue even after exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exception, cgitb

I recently came across `cgitb`. It's awesome, especially for the kind of thing I was trying to solve.

However, I have a simple requirement :

Is it possible to write out the exception trace on to a file and still continue post that as well. I know how to write out the exception to some file, but I am looking for the latter part.

Here's what I have tried:

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

'''
try:
   print(str(10/0))
except Exception as e:
  print "Hello"    
print "Tesla"
'''
```

So with the try-except block uncommented and without cgitb, I get `Tesla` printed out as well after the stack trace. But with cgitb enabled and the try-except block commented out, although I get a better stack trace, `Tesla` does not get printed out. 
Is there someway that we can still get `Tesla` printed out while using `cgitb`

Comment: If you catch the exception the `cgitab` won't trace it. `cgitab` is just a detailed traceback and it doesn't affect your code.

Comment: This is not an answer (I do not have enough reputation to comment), but please note that cgitb might be deprecated in Python3.8 and removed in Python 3.10:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0594/#cgitb

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, you can call [`cgitb.handler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgitb.html?highlight=cgitb.handler#cgitb.handler) yourself when you catch an exception.  Execution then continues, albeit from the handler rather than from the `raise` or so; Python does not have *resumable* exceptions.

Comment: ok so on your advice, i tried doing it this way : 
```except:
      cgitb.handler()``` and with that I get the `Tesla` string printed along with the stack trace. However, the stack trace is now being printed in html despite having cgitb.enable(format=text) in place. Any pointers?

Comment: @qre0ct: Python 3 has [`cgitb.text`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/cgitb.html?highlight=cgitb.text#cgitb.text), but that’s all I see.